# For words that can be a noun or not a noun, why does the noun have the emphasis at the start?

Tags: etymology, linguistics, emphasis

There are some pairs of words that can act as a noun or not a noun (a verb or an adjective.

For instance:

- rebel
- present
- compact

Why is it that the noun version of these words have their emphasis on the first syllable and the non-noun version of these words have their emphasis on the second syllable?

Are there any examples where the emphasis location is reversed?

Comment: In the English that I speak, the adjectives *rebel* and *present*  are stressed on the first syllable. However the adjective *compact* is stressed on the final syllable. So, for me, that part of your rule doesn't work and/or is inconsistent. I agree about the noun-verb divide though.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I hadn't thought about the difference between "a rebel" and "a rebel soldier"... good point!
(Or "My present is present under the tree")

Answer (score 6):

This [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun) article discusses the origins of the initial-stress-derived noun:

> In English, since the early modern period, polysyllabic nouns tend
>   to have an unstressed final syllable, while verbs do not. Thus, the
>   stress difference between nouns and verbs applies generally in
>   English, not just to otherwise-identical noun-verb pairs. The
>   frequency of such pairs in English is a result of the productivity of
>   class conversion.
>
> When "re-" is prefixed to a monosyllabic word, and the word gains
>   currency both as a noun and as a verb, it usually fits into this
>   pattern, although, as the following list makes clear, most words
>   fitting this pattern do not match that description.
>
> Many of these have first syllables that evolved from Latin
>   prepositions, although again that does not account for all of them. . . .
>
> When the stress is moved, the pronunciation, especially of vowels,
>   often changes in other ways as well. Most common is the reduction of a
>   vowel sound to a schwa when it becomes unstressed.